# How to host a site in Azure? I can't figure out how to hook it up to my domain

Tags: azure, iis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am using azure and have created a Windows 2016 server VM(not the classic mode). I have installed iis and opened up port 80. I can hit my ip and get the IIS page.

Now I am trying to host one of my very simple sites(per html page, with js/bootstrap).

I put it in IIS and set to an ip address(this was given to me as an option) instead of unassigned and left port 80.

I then went to namecheap and put my public ip from azure as my A record and in Azure I created a DNS Name and used that as the CNAME (for * and www) but I still get "not found" when I got to the domain name.

Comment: you probably forgot the NSG part

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my lab and I could browse the Website from my Azure with my own domain. Steps are below:

1. After add IIS feature in my VM, I opened 80 port in the NSG;

[image][image]
2. Configure a DNS name and static IP for the VM:

[image]

3. Add A records in my Domain provider:

[image]

4.Just wait a moment, I can browse it from my own domian:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: you don't use cname? What is NSG? I saw this but forgot is?

Comment: Hi,@chobo2, I have updated my answer. Go to your Azure VM,> Networking > Select Your NIC > Network security group >  Click that NSG > Inbound security rules >  Add.   You can see more details about Azure NSG in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg

Comment: Also, you can add CNAME records. In my test, I just use A records.

Comment: I am getting closer, I can get to the site if I do www.mysite.com (but if I do mysite.com) then I get 404. I guess something with url writing? I find it kinda werid though on my VM I can't reach my site at all(no matter how I type in my url). Yet from everywhere else I can.

Comment: Hi,@chobo2. What records did added? As I added in the answer: **A records with www and @**?